# Link shared library with each other shared libraries c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries

I've successfully create my shared library, **libA.so**.
All classes inside, have namspace common::A

```
ldd libA.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd632d000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f6497d19000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f6497b03000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6497743000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6497447000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6498243000)
```

Then, I need to create another library, B, that uses A. So I link it (-lA and -L< path_to_A >) and also compile with _I/. 
All classes inside, have namspace common::B

Compile and make **libB.so**, but:

**1)** Elipse put red X in code where I call A methods:

```
 Multiple markers at this line
- Symbol '<A_method>' could not be resolved
- Function '<A_method>' could not be resolved
```

**2)** Library A seems not linked to B:

```
ldd libB.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbcbfe000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f695ca59000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f695c842000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f695c483000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f695bf7e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f695d1d9000)
```

I can't understand why I don't have a link to A:

```
libA.so => .....
```

Any ideas?

## update

This is makefile (autogenerated by eclipse):

```
-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include src/network/mqtt/subdir.mk
-include src/data/subdir.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: libB.so

# Tool invocations
libB.so: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
    g++ -L/path_where_is_A_so/ -shared -o "libB.so" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(LIBRARIES)$(CC_DEPS)$(C++_DEPS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS)$(CXX_DEPS)$(OBJS)$(CPP_DEPS)$(C_DEPS) libB.so
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

Comment: I didn't mean to close it right away, only to suggest that it's a duplicate. If you think it doesn't answer your question, please comment and I'll reopen it.

Comment: I think is not the same case.. I'm working with shared library (.so) and not with static library (.a)

Comment: It works for both shared and static library, please give it a try.

Comment: sorry, I already include "-L<path_to_library>".. I update question!

Comment: It's not the `-L`, you nee dto call your library `libA.so`

Comment: please se my answer there, I do not mention `-L`, as it is no the problem

Comment: is already called libA and libB, I called A and B in post for semplicity only..

Comment: hmmm.. so I'm sorry. voting to reopen, but please fix this in the question.

Comment: Is libB actually using something defined in libA ? If it's not, the linker figures out it's not needed even if you link to it. Also, show the value of `$(LIBS)` (i.e. does it include `-lA`) which is in one of the included .mk files, or copy paste the command line that gets run when you do the linking.

Comment: ok nos, I definitely love you: you point me out to the problem. I use a libA method in B, but in an header only (inline method): is this for this that don't link libA.so?  [@echo $(LIBS) is ok]

Comment: moving in .cpp A's method invocation, everything works. Can you explain me why and if there's a way to make works also calling A'method from header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your libB doesn't use anything in libA, the linker might discard linking to libA (depending on whether the linker flag `--as-needed` is the default in your toolchain.)

To force libB to link to libA, specify the flag `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to appear before `-lA`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MakeFile then do things like this:

```
xxxxxx_la_SOURCES = $(FILES)
xxxxxx_la_CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)
xxxsxx_la_LDFLAGS = $(location_of_so_file)
```

Comment: my makefile is automatically-generated by eclipse.. so, in case, I have to find where I can set this values from project settings..

Comment: @Velthune: Don't bother, it's the kind of magic done by GNU Automake. I doubt Eclipse CDT uses the same mechanics (but I might be wrong, I don't use either of the two).

Comment: @Velthune http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html go through this